# Sed Replace Links to Specific Domains with the Anchor Text

Tags: html, regex, sed, hyperlink

I have a lot of static HTML files containing links for various domains.

I need to replace all the links for specific domains only with their anchor text.

Here's the command I managed to come up with so far:

`sed 's|<a .*example\.com.*>\(.*\)<\/a>|\1|Ig' file.html`

And here's an example of how it should work:

This

`<p>Some random text <a href="http://example.com/sample_page" title="Example Title">Anchor Text</a> | Some other random text <a href="http://example.org/">Different Anchor Text</a></p>`

Should become this:

`<p>Some random text Anchor Text | Some other random text <a href="http://example.org/">Different Anchor Text</a></p>`

The command above works great when there's only one link per line, but with more than one it removes all of them no matter of the domain leaving only the last one's anchor text.

I've found a few other similar topics here but couldn't adapt any of the solutions for my problem. Of course it's entirely possible that I might have missed an already existing topic with a solution I haven't tried. Let me know if I haven't explained the problem clear enough or if I have missed to provide some important info.

**//EDIT:**

After replacing `.*` with `[^>]*` and the command looking like this:

`sed 's|<a .*example\.com[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/a>|\1|Ig' file.html`

the first closing `</a>` remains and it's being removed from the last one.

Here's an example result:

`<p>Some random text Anchor Text</a> | Some other random text <a href="http://example.org/">Different Anchor Text</p>`

Replacing `.*` with `[^<>]*` yields the same result.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^>]*` or `[^<>]*`.

Comment: Sure. You left 2 `.*` intact. `sed 's|<a [^>]*example\.com[^>]*>\([^>]*\)</a>|\1|Ig' file.html` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thank you, it works perfect, could you post it as an answer, so I can accept it. And if it's not too much trouble, could you explain why it had to be replaced in the anchor text area as well?

Comment: Can title ever contain a `>`, e.g. could it be `title="Proof that 1 > 0"`? If so include that in your example as it will break most potential solutions (e.g. the currently accepted one).

Comment: @EdMorton - From what I've seen in the files I'd say that chances are around 0.05% or less for the title to contain a `>` and 4 or 5 errors in total are completely acceptable, and even if Wiktor Stribiżew's solution chokes in that particular case it's still perfectly fine for me, so I don't see a point in editing the question.  Of course if you say that this would make it more helpful for a wider audience and you think there's even a solution for the problem (using sed and not perl or something else), I'll make the edits.

Comment: It's more than just the case I mentioned that could fail, though. For example, try the accepted answer to work on `example.com` if `fooexample.com` existed instead and note it incorrectly operates on partial matches. Also `http://foo.com/example.command`. I'd put more effort into creating sample input that contains all of the cases you can think of that a tool would find hard to deal with instead of just the one simplest possible case and accepting an answer that only works for that. You might want to make it a different question though as people are probably skipping over this one by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that `.` matches any character, and it also matches any angle brackets.

You can "temper" the `.` with a negated bracket expression `[^<]`:

```
sed 's|<a [^>]*example\.com[^>]*>\([^>]*\)</a>|\1|Ig' file.html
```

This means that there can be no `>` inside the `a` tag. As `>` can appear in the contents you are dealing with, I guess a safer, though a bit slower alternative, is to use `[^<]` (as `<` should always be used as an entity).

Comment: @EdMorton: I know that in POSIX a dot matches a newline, I just answer so many NFA regex questions daily that I automatically type what I usually type. Right, the [commonly confused terms are "character class" and "bracket expression"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), I replaced  that one.

Comment: So in NFA regexps a dot doesn't match a newline? Which tools use those?

Comment: In Perl, JS, .NET, PHP (PCRE), Python, Java, Go, Swift/Objective C, Ruby (Oniguruma), R stringr or PCRE patterns - a dot will match any char but a newline without a special modifier. In QRegExp (Qt4), Tcl, R TRE regexp patterns, a dot will match any char by default.

Comment: I had no idea... thanks for the info (and just in time as I'm about to start writing my first Ruby On Rails code!).